# PID for Chrome appwindow is changing

Tags: bash, google-chrome, browser, pid

I am launching a new Chrome/Chromium window from the terminal with the --app parameter, trying to get the PID in the process, like so: `chrome --app="data:whatever" & PID=$!`

This returns a valid PID as long as the browser is not launched. However if the browser already had a window open, I get a message "Opening in existing browser session". There is still a number in the PID, but it has nothing to do with the process/window I just opened. When I run `kill -0 $PID`, the process is no longer there (but the app window still is of course).

Goal: I just want to know when someone closes the app that was launched form the script, and then execute some cleanup code.

Comment: I'd like to know this too!

Comment: I as well have this probelm